"Enable" custom icon to give it QGIS' default white border
QGIS 3.36.2, Python 3.12.3
If you hover over an icon of the default toolbars in QGIS (e.g. the Toolbox), then that icon gets a light grey background and a black border (leftmost) until you move your mouse again. Pressing it changes the background to a dark grey (until you stop). If you click on the same icon, then the background changes back to the regular grey, the icons gets a white border (second from the left) and e.g. the toolbox opens but the border still remains even after moving the mouse.

I create my own QAction/QIcon and QToolbar with the following code:
toolbar = QToolBar(self.title)
toolbar.setObjectName(self.title)
action_start = QAction("Start",toolbar)
action_start.triggered.connect(self.start)
icon_start = QIcon(self.pixmap_start)
action_start.setIcon(icon_start)
toolbar.addAction(action_start)
iface.addToolBar(toolbar)

Hovering over or pressing this custom icon changes the background and border around it as explained above.
Question: How do I "enable" my custom icon to give it the same white border after clicking it (I want to keep the same image) and how do I remove this "enabled" status again (the icon still has to be clickable to call the connected slot), e.g. when a "stop" button is clicked?
The docs mention that there's some kind of "mode", is that what adds the border or is that only used if you want to change the icon when you e.g. hover over it?

try action_start.setCheckable(True) when you create the action and then when you want the associated button to appear checked, action_start.setChecked(True).
If your action is showing/hiding a QDockWiget or QToolBar, as the Processing Toolbox button in your example does, then instead of creating a new action, you can use the QDockWiget or QToolBar instance's toggleViewAction() method to get an action that is already configured to show/hide that instance. You can then customize its icon, text, tooltip, etc. as needed.

Thanks! I changed my QAction, so it's now owned by self and I can access it everywhere in my code - I hope that's the correct way to handle actions. setCheckable turns a button/action into basically a checkbox: Click once and it gets the white "checked" border, click it again and that border vanishes. If you want to start a script with an action, then you have to take that into account and use setChecked accordingly every time (even outside of any ifs).
